# inserting new rows into SQL database

Tags: c#, php, mysql, sql, performance

I need to add new records to my SQL database using C# and php. I'm using this code:

```
string server = "http://www.naseelco.com/scorm/populatecode.php";
foreach (string code in codeList)//codelist has 200 items
 {
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(server);
     request.Method = "POST";
     string postData = "Code=" + code + "&Active=false";
     byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
     request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
     try
     {
         Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
         dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
         dataStream.Close();
     }
     catch
     {

     }
}
```

This is the content of the populatecode.php file:

```
<?php 
$Code = $_POST['Code'];
$Active = $_POST['Active'];
mysql_connect("localhost","myUserName","myPassword") or die ('Error updating database');
mysql_select_db("naseelc1_AC");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO codes (code,Active)VALUES ('$Code','$Active')");
echo $Code;
?>
```

But this code takes too much time to update the SQL database. My question is:
Is there a more efficient way to insert multiple records in a SQL database?

Comment: I am pretty sure a kitten is set on fire every time somebody asks for performance optimization while keeping the involved RDMS a secret.

Comment: You could insert them directly from C#, rather than http posting to php?

Comment: Whoa -- security issues! To start, be sure to use this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: @Erwin: the RDMS is MySQL, thus mysql_connect, mysql_select_db, & mysql_query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing when analyzing performance problems is to **test** and **verify** where you lose the time, not to *assume* that it's one special part of your system.

You say "*takes too much time to update the SQL database*", how do you know it's the INSERTs that are slowing you down?

First you have to measure the runtime of each part of your system. Then optimize that part.

Do not start optimization if you don't know which part to optimize.

Use a profiler or simple time measuring code using `microtime()` in PHP and the Stopwatch class in C# to calculate the runtime of a piece in your program to pinpoint the hotspots.

Assuming you have done all that and still find that `INSERTìng a single row is taking too long, then there are several areas to explore. Too many indexes is probably the first thing to check.

Seeing your program, I'd bet that Anders Abel is right and you are losing your time in the HTTP overhead, not during INSERTs

An alternative approache would be to send the whole list to the PHP code and then using a multi-row `INSERT` to insert everything with just a single statement:

```
  INSERT INTO codes (code,Active)
  VALUES 
  ('code_1', true),
  ('code_2', false),
  ('code_3', true),
  ('code_4', false),
  ('code_5', true)
```

But I still believe it's your concept of sending each code as one POST to the backend that is taking all the time...

Comment: It's actually not "premature" what the OP is doing (after all he does have a performance problem). But he starts at the wrong place.

Comment: valid point - I suppose i should have phrased more along the lines of, "don't guess what it is, know what it is!"

Answer (score 2):

The latency of 200 subsequent web requests is probably what's killing performance. Two suggestions:

- Change the php code to accept the complete list and loop through it.
- Use [`Parallel.Foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx) in the C# code to run the request in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

I know you weren't explicitly asking about security, but **ESCAPE YOUR USER FIELDS!** You should **NEVER EVER** directly use `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables in your queries. You **MUST** escape them first. Your current code is wide open to exploitation. You can escape each field using `mysql_real_escape_string()`

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Anyway, to actually answer your question, you probably want to look into [MySQL Connector/NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/). It's a library that connects directly to the MySQL server and integrates with the standard `System.Data` classes.